# combine fields and importrange in same

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a Form which splits into 3 sections

As a result of this. I have some fields which are duplicated.

**I am trying to pull rows from the 'FormData' spreadsheet page. Then display them in the 'Report' spreadsheet page.** Easy enough.

**I then want to merge the duplicated fields together in the report. Fields will only be merged where all but one field is empty.** 
i.e "Select Col2 where Col1 =''"

**FormData**
[image: Link To Image]

A = Timestamp

B = Name

C = Account Name

D = Contact

E = Notes

F = Task
G = Location

H = Freight to Store

I = When Goods Arrive

J = Freight to Customer

K = Priority

L = Assign To

M = Status

N = Supplier

O = Freight to Store

P = When Goods Arrive

Q = Freight to Customer

R = Priority

S = Assign To

T = Status

U = Priority

V = Assign To

W = Status

**Report**
[image: Link To Image]

FormData column to merge

B & C (Name:),(Account Name: Optional)
K, R, U (Priority:) 
L, S, V (Assign To:)
G & N: (Supplier:),(Location:)
H, O (Freight to Store:)
I, P (When Goods Arrive:)
J, Q (Freight to Customer: Optional)
M, T, W (Status:)

I have worked out how to merge cells. Using the below formula.

**Example for Merging Column B (Name) and Column C (Account Name)**
=iferror({query({IMPORTRANGE("URL","FormData!B2:B20000")},"Select Col1 where Col1 <>''");query({IMPORTRANGE("URL","FormData!B2:B20000"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","FormData!C2:C20000")},"Select Col2 where Col1 =''")})

I am not sure if this goes beyond using a formula or if a script will need to be created.

Either way I will require assistance.

I greatly appreciate any help offered. Am working on this until I have figured it out.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not sure if this goes beyond using a formula"? Is your formula working or not? If not working, Have you tried to split the formula on its parts in order to find which one isn't working?